# Validation Error Handing Laravel Sanctum Api in JSON

Tags: laravel, api, rest, laravel-sanctum

Laravel usually use following for request validation.

```
 $request->validate([
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users', 'required_without_all:phone'],
            'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
            'phone' => ['required', 'string', 'max:13', 'unique:users', 'required_without_all:email'],
        ]);
```

This method only add $error variable that can be access using blade files as it render on server only. But now i am using as api Sanctum that which it just show 404. My guess it just redirect back to request and $error is session which can can access with PHP only.

there is work around for it

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
                'email' => ['string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users', 'required_without_all:phone'],
                'password' => ['required', 'confirmed', Rules\Password::defaults()],
                'phone' => ['string', 'max:13', 'unique:users', 'required_without_all:email'],
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response()->json($validator->errors());
    }
```

That is just adding extra line i don't want that using this line every time. **Can somebody help me for edit validate function which just return any $error as json only**.

**Clarified Answer**

I am self certified noob let me make it like my brain can understand using fetch

```
let y = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/register", {
  method: "POST", // or 'PUT'
  headers: {
    "Accept" : "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(x),
}).then(response => response.json());
console.log(y);
```

I am thinking it a wrong way as there is {"Accept":application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json",} and Accept is important nothing needed to do in back-end.

Comment: It's most likely because of Accept header. Could you post the result of         `dd($request->header('Accept'));` in the controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to handle this yourself.

Just make sure your request sends the right header: `Accept: application/json`

This [helps](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php#L426) Laravel to know that you want a json response instead of a redirect (that caused the 404).

### [Sample snippet](https://laravelplayground.com/#/snippets/d002b8e8-0dc3-4141-9ced-4dcc88318e97)

Comment: on the server side how to accept application/json in laravel ?

Comment: @PuneetSharma it is a header sent with the request to the server so its the client side

Comment: let y = await fetch("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/create-account", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(x),
}).then(response => response.json());

Comment: something like that

Comment: Change `Content-Type` to `Accept` and see if it works.

Comment: nothing changes

Comment: I added a sample snippet.

Comment: $request->validate or request()->validate just redirect back so 404 and and laravel have some session error that can access only by the using $error only

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240860/discussion-between-puneet-sharma-and-mostafa-bahri).